# Why do I need Safe Navigation operator (Elvis) if I am initializing an object in Angular

Tags: angular, safe-navigation-operator

Angular 8, Django 3. I am displaying an object `Restaurant` in a view `RestaurantView`. The `RestaurantView` gets the `Restaurant` on the `ngOnInit` method:

```
    restaurant: Restaurant
    id: string 

    getrestaurantdetail(id):void {
      this.restaurantservice.restaurantdetail(id).subscribe(restaurant => this.restaurant = restaurant)
    }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
    this.getrestaurantdetail(this.id)
  }

}
```

and then is diplayed in the html file `<h1>{{restaurant.name}}</h1>`. If I dont put the Elvis operator in the html file as `<h1>{{restaurant?.name}}</h1>` the view displays correctly but I get a console error `property "name" not defined`. I dont understand if the `RestaurantView` is returning a `Restaurant` object on initialization why I would ever get this null error.

Comment: This is because the request which returns `restaurant` is asynchronous. And that it will be `undefined` when the component is first rendered, until `restaurantdetail` is returned

Comment: ok, so is the correct approach to use the Elvis operator or to have a *ngIf statement or does it really not matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Either one will do!

Comment: thanks, if you post as answer i will accept! Just to be clear, every Angular html component will have the elvis operator or ngIf statement then?

Comment: Yes! You got it right!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the request which returns `restaurant` is asynchronous. Therefore, `restaurant` will be undefined when the component is first rendered, until the observable from the `restaurantdetail` method is returned.

The elvis operator, also known as the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator),

> guards against null and undefined values in property paths. Here, it
>   protects against a view render failure if item is null.

Therefore, it is required on your HTML template:

```
<h1>{{restaurant?.name}}</h1>
```

An alternative to doing so would be to use the [ngIf](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngif) structural directive which checks if `restaurant` is null or undefined.

```
<h1 *ngIf="restaurant">{{restaurant.name}}</h1>
```